# UIView not appearing on xib

Tags: ios, uiview, xib

I am trying to make a UIView appear as a rounded box on terms and conditions screen as seen here

[image]

When I add an UIView to the xib IB the UIView doesn't show up. But if I add a UIButton to the view then I see the view. How can I make the UIView always visible to a specified frame size?

Comment: what are the background and border colours of the view ?

Comment: White is the background color, I haven't set any border colors

Comment: Are you using storyboards, or standalone xib files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't connect the view to the controller.